# How to mention someone in comments of gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

Is there any way to mention someone when a comment/reply is added?

I've tried `@someone` but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

So far (Gerrit 3.0.0) you can't do that. It is requested for as a feature in [Issue 3534](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=3534).

The general workflow people tend to use is to either add as Reviewer/CC if some person is not already in it, so a notification will be sent.

Answer (score 2):

Mentions were added in [Gerrit 3.7](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/3.7.html#mention-user-support)